# React-Native react-navigation from another file

Tags: authentication, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have problem with navigation in RN, so I thought you could help me. I can't find any way to navigate from my "settings" tab to my "SignedOut", [this is my repo](https://github.com/MarioRozic/ReactTemplateAuth), code is not complicated, all you have to look is in "navigation" and "screens" folder. Thing is my "settings" file is in one file "MainTabNavigator" and SignedOut is in "RootNavigation", and when i try something like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("SignedOut");
```

nothing happend, here is my function for this:

```
onSignOut()
.then(() => {
    console.log('Logout!');
    this.props.navigation.navigate("SignedOut");
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
})
```

I do get this log printed out so it should call this navigation method successfully. Do you have any ideas why? I mean, I think that this is the reason maybe I am missing something here?

This is what my MainTabNavigator looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import ListScreen from '../screens/ListScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';
import WordDetails from '../screens/WordDetails';
import DrawerMenu from './drawerDesign/Drawer';

export default DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    List: {
      screen: ListScreen,
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsScreen,
    },
    WordDetails: {
      screen: WordDetails,
    },
  }, {
    contentComponent: DrawerMenu,
    drawerWidth: 200,
    drawerPosition: "right",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
      itemsContainerStyle: {
        marginVertical: 0,
        opacity: 0.6

      },
      iconContainerStyle: {
        opacity: 0.6
      },
      style: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 35,
      },
    }
  }
);
```

SingedOutNavigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, Easing, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

import SignIn from '../screens/SignInScreen';
import Register from '../screens/RegisterScreen';


const headerStyle = {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    backgroundColor: '#2b303b',
};

export default StackNavigator(
    {
        SignIn: {
            screen: SignIn,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: "Prijavi se",
                headerStyle,
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    color: '#f5f5f5'
                },
            },
        },
        Register: {
            screen: Register,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: "Prijavi se",
                headerStyle,
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    color: '#f5f5f5'
                },
            },
        }
    },
    {
        headerMode: "none",
        transitionConfig: () => ({
            transitionSpec: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: Easing.step0,
                timing: Animated.timing,
            },
            screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
                const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps
                const { index } = scene

                const height = layout.initHeight
                const translateY = position.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
                    outputRange: [height, 0, 0],
                })

                const opacity = position.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [index - 1, index - 0.99, index],
                    outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
                })

                return { opacity, transform: [{ translateY }] }
            },
        }),
    }
);
```

And from this "Settings" Screen i want to go on this "SignIn" from "SignedOutNavigator"..

Comment: Are you sure that the render of the RootNavigator is called? Can you confirm that by putting a console.log or a break point [here](https://github.com/MarioRozic/ReactTemplateAuth/blob/master/navigation/RootNavigation.js#L80)?

Comment: Do you mean when I enter app for the 1st time or when I press button ?

Comment: When you press the button to sign out.

Comment: nope it does not, what if I use redux and that global state "signedIn", it could do the trick ...

Comment: @jkarr thank you sooo much, I didnt even thought about checking that ..I made simple Event that triggers when I hit the button and update my state "SignedIn" to false ...if you want put that in comment bellow and i will mark it as done and helpful.

Comment: You are welcome mate :)

Comment: Do you have any other solution rather than events ?

Comment: Basically I'm new to react and I prefer using as less as I can in order not to have dependencies that I can't understand. In my opinion you should re-factor the RootNavigation and remove the class. Just export the StackNavigator that it's in the createRootNavigator. If understand your code correctly then you shouldn't need any events. Also I can't understand why you have pushNotifications in your RootNavigator I don't think that push notification should be part of the navigation unless you have some weird requirement.

Comment: yea I understand ..I am pretty new to RN too ...well RootNav is my main I mean its file that renders my app ..all logic goes from that file ... push notif is for later usage, I've putted it there cuz that file renders 1st on app load so I can push token to my server automatically, thanks anyways I will sure check if I could solve this w/o events but this works pretty nice ...even better than I imagined it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you are building an application that some of it's screens are only available when the user is singed in.

So when the user logout you should clear the history of the navigation, in order for the user to become unable to navigate back using the back hardware button.

You should do something like:

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0, key: null, actions: [ NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "SignedOut" }) ]
}));
```

Comment: Should I define that NavigationActions 1st?

Comment: @MarioRozic NavigationActions are provided from react navigation. Check out the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions). it also has some examples :)

Comment: ohh yea sry i didnt include it from module ...but it still doesnt redirect me :/

Answer (score 0):

I Believe u need to declare the screens in `app.js`.

```
import YOURSCREENfrom './src/screens/YOURSCREEN'

const Routes = {
    YOURSCREEN: { screen: YOURSCREEN}
}
```

Then u can call `this.props.navigation.navigate("YOURSCREEN");`

Comment: ty for reply but it doesn't fix my issue :(